# Why vue-cli-3 won't build, "can't find 'wepack'"?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue-cli-3

Since recently got this error when trying to run `npm run build` saying webpack could not be found in the mini-css-extract-plugin. I can't figure out what I've might have changed to cause it.

I've created a release branch recently, but I don't have a lot of changes (in the package.json) compared the master branch where the build still works. However a few weeks ago (before my holidays) it still worked and I can't get my finger on the problem.

#### Also here is the initial Error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\EnviDat\Frontend\envidat_frontend\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:8:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\EnviDat\Frontend\envidat_frontend\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\cjs.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
```

I've have tried install the dependencies in the node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin folder manually via `npm install`, but then I've just got other dependencies which couldn't be loaded. When installing the them.

#### I ended up when I've got the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 0)
Failed to load plugin import: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-import'
Referenced from: D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\@vue\eslint-config-airbnb\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb-base\index.js
Referenced from: D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\@vue\eslint-config-airbnb\index.js
Referenced from: D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\.eslintrc.js
    at PoolWorker.fromErrorObj (D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\thread-loader\dist\WorkerPool.js:262:12)
    at D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\thread-loader\dist\WorkerPool.js:204:29
    at mapSeries (D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\thread-loader\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3625:14)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
    at Plugins.load (D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\plugins.js:104:29)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Plugins.loadAll (D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\plugins.js:165:21)
    at loadFromDisk (D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\config-file.js:529:35)
    at load (D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\config-file.js:587:20)
    at configExtends.reduceRight (D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\config-file.js:453:36)
    at Array.reduceRight (<anonymous>)
    at applyExtends (D:\EnviDat\Frontend_develop\envidat_frontend\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\config-file.js:431:26)

 @ multi ./src/main.js
```

At which point I'm lost, I could figure out anything online, so I've reinstall all the node_modules, still the same result. Also I've tried to go a clean install with `npm ci`, still the same problem.

#### I can't figure it out why the error happens and what to change to make it work again

The dependencies in the package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
    "leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant": "^0.7.0",
    "m-markdown-preview": "^1.0.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "*",
    "seedrandom": "^2.4.3",
    "skeleton-placeholder": "^1.0.0",
    "ssri": "^5.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.7.0",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.5",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-localstorage": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.8.95",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.1.0 || ^5.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^4.1.0 || ^5.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^4.1.0 || ^5.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^4.1.0 || ^5.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.1.9",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-url": "^8.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  },
```

The the full package.json is here:
https://github.com/EnviDat/envidat_frontend/blob/release/Navigation_integration/package.json

And the vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: './',
  assetsDir: './static',
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  css: {
    modules: false,
    sourceMap: true,
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    storybook: {
      allowedPlugins: ['define'],
    },
  },
};
```

### How do I need to change the dependencies or config to make it build again?

Comment: I hope you had nice holidays! Here: https://github.com/EnviDat/envidat_frontend/commit/198e98ca7c7e92608d6f4602d0c4464fb24e644d#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2 you removed webpack etc... So...

Comment: @madflow Right, as far as I understood the vue-cli-service is supposed to have the webpack under the hood. So when installing the vue-cli-service I'd expect it be installed again.

Comment: This is one of those that would need to be cloned and replicated. I would suggest generating a fresh project with the settings you want and if it compiles then copy over your src files to it, and try and modify the prescribed build as little as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I removed package-lock.json and npm told me about the missing dependencies. I installed these. When I ran the build it wanted some more deps regarding eslint-loader.

In summary:

`npm install --save-dev webpack html-webpack-plugin typescript vue-loader babel-loader eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-webpack`

and

`npm run build`

yielded

`DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.`

This does no really answer the question what exactly is going on here though :/

Comment: This work thank you.
I also tried updating these packages via ```npm i @vue/cli-plugin-babel @vue/cli-plugin-eslint @vue/cli-service @vue/eslint-config-airbnb``` that seemed to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
npm i -g webpack webpack-cli
```

To see if it work

Comment: It still ended up with the error of the Thread Loader not working.